# Accessing call stack elements

Tags: stack, callstack

I have multiple elements in my call stack, I want to access the first element that was stored inside the stack. For that I need to empty all the elements of the stack on top of the focused element right?. While doing this, where are all the other elements stored?

I am expecting that the elements are being stored inside another stack, is that right?